# Bootstrap 3 input, dropdown list, button within input-group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to make input, dropdown list and button and it looks like there is no way to make in this order within input-group. Any ideas?

**Dropdown | Input | Button (works):**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span>Search By</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                 </button>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
       <input type="search" name="searchBy" id="searchBy" class="form-control" />
       <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button id="filter" class="btn btn-default" >
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
           </button>
        </span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hvjv6fjc/

But I want **Input | Dropdown | Button** and there is some issue

https://jsfiddle.net/4aexouyf/

Comment: And what is the issue? Did you read the Bootstrap documentation clearly?

Comment: If you look at the second fiddle you will see the issue. Yes I read documentation. I thought since everything within input-group it shouldn't look like this (2nd example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. This was my mistake.

```
  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group">
                          <input type="search" name="searchBy" id="searchBy" class="form-control" />
                          <div class="input-group-btn">
                              <div class="btn-group">
                                  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                      <span>Choose</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                                  </button>


                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </div>
                                <button id="filter" class="btn btn-default" >
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" name="searchBy" id="searchBy" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle dropdown-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <span>Search By</span> <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button id="filter" class="btn btn-default" >
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

add a custom css class *.dropdown-button*

**Css**

```
.dropdown-button {
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

I updated this snippet, check this too.

https://jsfiddle.net/4aexouyf/3/